# What is the best way for initializing a fixed-length string in Ada?

Tags: string, ada, bounded-types

I want to initialize a fixed-length `String` in Ada more or less like following:

```ada
S : String (1..256) := ("Hello", others => Character'Val (0));
```

I obtain an error while trying to compile. **Is there any way to achieve something similar to the above?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your code does not compile is that String is an array of Character so the equivalent would be

```ada
s : String(1..256) := (1 => 'H',
                       2 => 'e',
                       3 => 'l',
                       4 => 'l',
                       5 => 'o',
                       others => Character'Val(0));
```

Which is clearly far from ideal.

Another way is to use the Move procedure in [Ada.Strings.Fixed][1].

```ada
Move(Target => s,
     Source => "Hello",
     Pad => Character'Val(0));
```

But this can't be done in the declaration.

Finally, this compiles :

```ada
s : String(1..256) := "Hello" & (6..256 => Character'Val(0));
```

But I find it less clear
[1]: http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html

Comment: "But I find it less clear" - there is no logical, clear string handling in Ada ;)

Comment: It depends considering the fact that String are just arrays of characters, The last solution I proposed is quite logical but different from what you can find in C++ or Java for example. Using Move is more encapsulated the way these two languages would do the same thing and show strings as an object

Answer (score 1):

I would usually do something like

```
Hello : constant String := "Hello";

Desired_Length : constant := 256;

S : String := Hello & (1 .. Desired_Length - Hello'Length => Character'Val (0) );
```

or

```
(Hello'Length + 1 .. Desired_Length => ...);
```